# Group by two rows and and subtract a numeric field

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, common-table-expression

Let's say I have data like this:

```
   Table
   Num1      Grp        Type          Cost
   ----      ---        ----          ----
   12X       XXX        OLD             17
   12X       XXX        NEW             23
```

I have many rows of data that I'm trying to do this to, this is just one example

What I am trying to achieve is to roll both of these up, and take a difference of NEW - OLD Cost column

Desired results:

```
   Table
   Num1      Grp          Cost
   ----      ---          ----
   12X       XXX          6
```

The approach I'm using is with 2 CTE's like so:

```
WITH OLD as (Select * from table where type ='OLD')
, NEW as (Select * from table where type ='NEW')
```

Then

```
Select Num1, Grp, n.Cost - o.cost as Cost
from OLD o INNER JOIN NEW n on o.Num1 = n.Num1 and o.grp = n.group
```

However, the two CTE's that I actually have, are huge queries, is there any way I can maybe accomplish that in a simpler way? I feel that having two CTE's is just an overload and would rather have it done in a neater way.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use aggregation:

```
select name, grp,
       sum(case when type = 'NEW' then cost 
                when type = 'OLD' then - cost
           end)
from t
group by name, grp
```